# How to Takeover a Folder when even Admins and SYSTEM has Access Denied?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

I'm having a strange problem; a user seems to have 'tweaked' the permission of a folder so that not even a Domain Admin nor the SYSTEM account can take it over.

- `icacls Folder /T /C /Q /RESET` --> Access is denied
- `takeown /f Folder` --> Access is denied
- `icacls Folder` --> Access is denied

Not sure what I can do at this moment...

Answer (score 5):

You need to [take ownership](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx) of the folder (and its child objects, from the sounds of things), at which point you'll be able to change the permissions.  An administrative account (or the current owner) is generally required to perform this operation.

[Using ICALCS, the syntax is](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html):

```
  ICACLS name /setowner user [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
```

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of `takeown`? As to the user... I'm not really sure who actually created the folder; it's just called "Folder"...

Comment: @pepoluan elevated command line?  I see Server2008R2.  Make sure UAC isn't getting in the way.

Comment: Yes, elevated command line.

Comment: @pepoluan  Try the GUI.  Should have the best results using an elevated explorer instance on a remote computer, and navigating to the parent of this folder via the administrative share... `\\[server]\C$\[path]\` (or whatever drive the folder resides on).